# How to grant restricted internet access to guest VM on QEMU debian host?

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, qemu

I have a Windows 10 guest virtualized by QEMU 3.1.0 on a Debian 10 host. This VM shall not be allowed to access the internet except outgoing connections to a specific server (lets say `git.example.com:22`). What is the best way to configure such network?

The users accessing the VM are having root access inside the guest and may modify anything inside (even the guests firewall). So I want a host side solution to prevent unallowed internet access. The best solution would be that the VM can access the server as with full internet access.

What I have tried is to start qemu with a restricted user network configuration and forward the guest TCP connection:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -m 8192 -hda VM.vmdk \
-device rtl8139,netdev=inet0,mac=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF \
-netdev user,id=inet0,net=192.168.0.0/24,restrict=yes,guestfwd=tcp:git.example.com:22-tcp:git.example.com:22
```

Which gives this error message:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: Invalid guest forwarding rule 'tcp:git.example.com:22-tcp:git.example.com:22'
```

And also IP addresses are not working:

```
$ qemu-system-x86_64 -m 8192 -hda VM.vmdk \
-device rtl8139,netdev=inet0,mac=AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF \
-netdev user,id=inet0,net=192.168.0.0/24,restrict=yes,guestfwd=tcp:1.2.3.4:22-tcp:1.2.3.4:22
```

Which gives this error message:

```
qemu-system-x86_64: Conflicting/invalid host:port in guest forwarding rule 'tcp:1.2.3.4:22-tcp:1.2.3.4:22'
```

What am I doing wrong here? Can I achieve a solution with the host's firewall (iptables) if qemu can't tackle this problem out of the box?

Thanks a lot for your help.